# correctly reading data from a text file with json format in it

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, csv, txt

Imagine I have a text file with the following two observations:

```json
liame@ziggo.nl:horse22| homeAddress = {
  "city": "AMSTERDAM",
  "houseNumber": "5",
  "houseNumberAddition": null,
  "postalCode": "1111 AN",
  "street": "Walker",
  "__typename": "ShopperAddress"
}
johndoe@live.nl:pizzalover1 | homeAddress = {
  "city": "NEW YOK",
  "houseNumber": "23",
  "houseNumberAddition": null,
  "postalCode": "9999 HV",
  "street": "Marie Curie",
  "__typename": "ShopperAddress"
}
```

Is there a way to read in this text file in such a way that the data frame looks like this:

```py
username1       username2    city        housenumber  housenumber_addition  postalcode   street      typename
liam@ziggo.nl   horse22      AMSTERDAM   5            null                  1111 AN      Walker      ShopperAddress
johndoe@live.nl pizzalover1  NEW YORK    23           null                  9999 HV      Marie Curie ShopperAddress
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text file shows that there is a pattern to how the data is encoded:

```
<username1>:<username2> | homeAddress = {
    <json_data>
}
```

We are going to parse the file in 2 passes: first pass to separate one record
from another and second pass to pick out the fields within a record:

- A record ends on a line containing a single "}" character
- Use regex to separate the fields inside a record

```py
import json, re
import pandas as pd

data = []
pattern = re.compile(r"(.+?):(.+?)\s*\|\s*homeAddress = (.+)", re.DOTALL)

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    record = ""
    for line in fp:
        record += line

        if line == "}\n":
            m = pattern.match(record)
            if m:
                username1 = m.group(1)
                username2 = m.group(2)
                home_address = json.loads(m.group(3))
                data.append({
                    "username1": username1,
                    "username2": username2,
                    **home_address
                })
            record = ""

df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns={"__typename": "typename"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rework a bit your original text to make it a valid dictionary/JSON and feed it to [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.3/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html):

```
(pd.read_json('[%s]'%re.sub(r'([^:\n]+):([^\|:]+)\s*\|\s*homeAddress = {',
                            r',{\n  "username1":"\1",\n  "username2":"\2",',
                            text)[1:])
   .rename(columns={'houseNumber': 'housenumber',
                    'houseNumberAddition': 'housenumber_addition',
                    'postalCode': 'postalcode',
                    '__typename': 'typename'})
)
```

output:

```
         username1     username2       city  housenumber  housenumber_addition postalcode       street        typename
0   liame@ziggo.nl       horse22  AMSTERDAM            5                   NaN    1111 AN       Walker  ShopperAddress
1  johndoe@live.nl  pizzalover1     NEW YOK           23                   NaN    9999 HV  Marie Curie  ShopperAddress
```

intermediate reworked data:

```
[{
  "username1":"liame@ziggo.nl",
  "username2":"horse22",
  "city": "AMSTERDAM",
  "houseNumber": "5",
  "houseNumberAddition": null,
  "postalCode": "1111 AN",
  "street": "Walker",
  "__typename": "ShopperAddress"
}
,{
  "username1":"johndoe@live.nl",
  "username2":"pizzalover1 ",
  "city": "NEW YOK",
  "houseNumber": "23",
  "houseNumberAddition": null,
  "postalCode": "9999 HV",
  "street": "Marie Curie",
  "__typename": "ShopperAddress"
}]
```